# WebServlet longest match

Tags: java, servlets

I have servlets with WebServlet annotations and it appears that it is not respecting the longest match.

I have

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/junk"})
public class ControllerOne extends HttpServlet {
```

and

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/junk/other"})
public class ControllerTwo extends HttpServlet {
```

A request to /junk/other seems to end up calling the ControllerOne instead of ControllerTwo as I would expect.  Why is this? Is there any way to enforce longest match?

Comment: Which servlet container are you using? This should work as you expect. Note that they do require **exact matches**. For example, `/junk/other/foo` should not match either of these servlets.

Comment: Tomcat 8.0.32. And the request is exact matching ControllerTwo but ControllerOne is getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Seems like

```
@WebServlet("/junk/other")
```

works for me.